# Improving regex for splitting printf format strings

Tags: python, regex, printf

I try to split format strings, which are used for example in the C function `printf`, into its parts with help of regex. I define a "part" of the format string as surroundings of a specifier (the surrounding defined in a greedy manner until another specifier is encountered). For example for the format string

```
My %s is %d!
```

I would like to get two parts:

1. `My %s is` as surroundings of the specifier`%s` which are determined in greedy fashion until `%d` gets in the way.
2. `%d!` as surroundings of the specifier`%d`

I assume, that the format string is correct and don't have to check its correctness. However, I have to consider that `%%` is not a specifier, but is used to print the character `%`. Thus the format string `My %s is %d %%!` would yield only two parts `My %s is` and `%d %%!`.

I came up with a regex (see also [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rI7cO0/1)), which seems to work:

```
reg="((([^%]*(%%)*)*)(%[^%])(([^%]*(%%)*)*))"
a=re.findall(reg, "My %s is %d %%!")
>>> a[0][0]
'My %s is '
>>> a[1][0]
'%d %%!'
```

But being new to regular expression I'm pretty sure it is not a very good or high-performance one (for example this lot of `*`s looks strange, but I'm not able to come up with something more elegant).

I would be very thankful for suggestions how to improve this expression.

Comment: I think you are looking for http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com  We are here for *specific* questions, not recommendations.

Comment: When you repost there, please do a better job explaining what you want, because I'm not understanding why you want the output to be the way it is, or why you would want to do this in the first place.